# Acessing position i,j in prolog (joining predicates)

Tags: list, matrix, indexing, prolog

Can anyone tell how can I join these two predicates,

```
listAt([L1|L2], 0, L) :- L = L1.
listAt([L1|L2], I, L) :- I1 is I - 1, listAt(L2, I1, L). 
%return list index I from list of lists

valAt([H|T], 0, V) :- V = H.
valAt([H|T], J, V) :- J1 is I - 1, valAt(T, J1, V).
%returns element index J of list
```

, so I can acess element [i][j] from list of lists?

I can do it manually by writing

```
| ?- listAt( [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ], 1, L), valAt(L, 1, V).
L = [4,5,6],
V = 5 ?
yes
```

, but if in .pl file I write

```
At([H|T],I,J,X) :- 
listAt([H,T],I,V),
valAt(V,J,X).
```

, I get

> operator expected after expression
>   ( [H|T] , I , J , X ) :- listAt ( [H|T] , I , V ) , valAt ( V , J , X ) .

Thanks for any helping

Comment: I assume that the capitalization of `At` is a typo since a predicate must start with a lower case letter (should be `at`). Also, your second `valAt` predicate says, `J1 is I - 1`, which should be `J1 is J - 1`. Finally, `[H,T]` in the `at` predicate should be `[H|T]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and fixed a couple of what appeared to be typographical errors, and made a couple of non-consequential changes, and it seems to work fine:

```
listAt([HL|_], 0, HL).           %EDIT: used '_' for a term not used; compress
listAt([_|TL], I, L) :-          %EDIT: used '_' for a term not used
    I1 is I - 1,
    listAt(TL, I1, L).
%return list @ index I from list of lists

valAt([H|_], 0, H).              %EDIT: used '_' for a term not used; compress
valAt([_|T], J, V) :-            %EDIT: used '_' for a term not used
    J1 is J - 1,                 %FIXED: replaced I with J
    valAt(T, J1, V).
%returns element @ index J of list

at(L, I, J, X) :-                %FIXED: Changed "At" to "at"; changed [H|T] to L
    listAt(L, I, V),             %FIXED Changed [H,T] to L
    valAt(V, J, X).
```

And an example:

```
| ?- at( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], 2, 2, X).

X = 9 ? ;

no
| ?-
```

And

```
| ?- at([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 1, 1, X ).

X = 5 ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

Note the use of underscores for unused terms in the predicate. If you have a single use of an uninstantiated term in Prolog, you will get a "singleton" warning. In Prolog, if you need a term in a position but don't need to use it, you can use `_` or a variable name starting with an underscore (e.g., `_List`).

Note you can also instantiate right in the predicate head. So you can replace `listAt([L1|_], 0, L) :- L = L1.` with simply, `listAt([HL|_], 0, HL).`.

Comment: Hm, thanks. Why do prolog says "no"? Sorry, but I'm a newbie in this language.

Comment: @user2884323 It says "no" because I asked it to provide more solutions (I entered `;`) and there were no more. I am using GNU Prolog in this case.

Comment: I see. That was really helpful, greets.

Comment: Cool. I added a few more comments to explain more items.